# MySQL select where no matches in join

Tags: mysql, join

How would I do following in MySQL:

I have 3 tables:

**user**: id

**communication**: id, creation_date

**user_communication**: user_id, communication_id

Now I want to select all users that have had **no** communication since a given date.

Following is what I have now, but I'm stuck on how to get what I described above.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_communication uc ON uc.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN communication c ON c.id = uc.communication_id
WHERE c.creation_date < '2013-8-1';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` condition is undoing the `left join`.  The initial solution would be to move it to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_communication uc ON uc.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN communication c ON c.id = uc.communication_id and c.creation_date < '2013-8-1';
```

But this doesn't do what you want.  This retrieves all records.  If you had a creation date field in the `select` clause, it would be NULL when there is record before that date.

For no communication since that date, you can do a "double" negative" query.  Look for records that are since that date, and return the mismatches:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     user_communication uc
     ON uc.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     communication c
     ON c.id = uc.communication_id and c.creation_date >= '2013-08-01'
WHERE c.creation_date is NULL;
```

EDIT:

I see.  The problem is a little more subtle than my answer above.  Each user has multiple communications, so none can be later.  The following query tests this by grouping by `u.id` and then checking that there are no non-`NULL` values from the above join:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     user_communication uc
     ON uc.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     communication c
     ON c.id = uc.communication_id and c.creation_date >= '2012-08-01'
group by u.id
having min(c.creation_date is null) = 1;
```

Comment: Correct on all counts

Comment: Probably a better solution than the one I provided.

Comment: Hmm I'm testing this now, however it's not working for me. I made a sqlfiddle to show it, it should not return user 1, but still does: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9be37/1

Comment: I also added an answer with what I have now, which I think works

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_communication uc ON uc.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM communication WHERE creation_date < '2013-8-1') c 
ON c.id = uc.communication_id
WHERE c.id is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research and help I have following query, which seems to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.id)
FROM user u
WHERE (SELECT coalesce(max(c.creation_date), '1900-01-01 00:00:00') last_creation_date
       FROM user inneru 
       LEFT JOIN user_communication uc ON uc.user_id = inneru.id
       LEFT JOIN communication c ON c.id = uc.communication_id
       WHERE inneru.id = u.id) < '2012-08-01'
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dfad/10